# Query to extract all the entries by month and year

Tags: mysql, sql

Many thanks for the help on my last question on extracting price data and putting it into month by years – the query works well to get the max price based on my criteria.

What I need now is a query to extract all the entries, so I can make a view that I can filter on filter on grid_calc.`SexCategory`, grid_calc.`Teeth`, grid_calc.`WtMin’, grid_calc.`WtMax `and grid_header.`BuyerID`,

This is what I currently have.

Q. can I reuse this or do I need to recreate a new query. If recreate how would I go about it?

```
select grid_calc.`FeedType`,
       grid_calc.`SexCategory`,
       grid_calc.`Teeth`,
       grid_calc.`Price`,
       grid_calc.`WtMin`,
       grid_calc.`WtMax`,
       grid_header.`BuyerID`,
    monthname(grid_header.`EntryDate`) as Month,
        max(case when year(grid_header.`EntryDate`) = 2018 then price else 0 end) as price_2018,
        max(case when year(grid_header.`EntryDate`) = 2019 then price else 0 end) as price_2019,
        max(case when year(grid_header.`EntryDate`) = 2020 then price else 0 end) as price_2020,
        max(case when year(grid_header.`EntryDate`) = 2021 then price else 0 end) as price_2021,
        max(case when year(grid_header.`EntryDate`) = 2022 then price else 0 end) as price_2022
FROM grid_calc
  INNER JOIN grid_header
     ON grid_header.`EntryDate` > '2018-01-01'
     AND grid_calc.`GridID` = grid_header.`GridID`
WHERE 1=1 
   AND grid_header.`EntryDate` > '2018-01-01' 
group by monthname(grid_header.`EntryDate`)
order by max(month(grid_header.`EntryDate`));
```

FY grid_calc table looks like this.

| GridID | Price | Teeth | FeedType | WtMin | WtMax | SexCategory | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9851 | 5.3 | 2 | 434 | 300 | 340 | 438 | 140177 |
| 9851 | 5.2 | 2 | 434 | 260 | 280 | 438 | 140178 |
| 9851 | 5.25 | 4 | 434 | 300 | 420 | 438 | 140179 |
| 9851 | 5.2 | 6 | 434 | 300 | 420 | 438 | 140180 |
| 9851 | 5.15 | 8 | 434 | 300 | 420 | 438 | 140181 |
| 9851 | 4.05 | 8 | 434 | 320 | 500 | 439 | 140182 |

grid_header table looks like this

| GridID | EntryDate | BuyerID | ConfigID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9851 | 23/01/2019 | 236 | 1 |
| 9851 | 23/01/2019 | 236 | 1 |
| 9851 | 23/01/2019 | 236 | 1 |
| 9851 | 23/01/2019 | 236 | 1 |
| 9851 | 23/01/2019 | 236 | 1 |
| 9851 | 23/01/2019 | 236 | 1 |

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: But seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Thnx - I am using a plugin called wpdatatables to handle the front end/WP stuff.. Just need to get the data into year columns..